# Beautiful Soup Parse Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've captured the following html using `BS4`, but can't seem to search for the artist tag.
I've assigned this block of code to a variable called **container**, and then tried

```
print container.tr.td["artist"]
```

without luck. 
Any advice appreciated?

```
<tr class="item">
  <!-- <td class="image"><a href="https://www.stargreen.com/kool-as-the-gang-44415.html" title="KOOL AS THE GANG " class="product-image"><img src="https://www.stargreen.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/K/o/KoolAsTheGang.jpg" width="135" height="135" alt="KOOL AS THE GANG " /></a></td> -->
  <td class="date">Sat, 30 Dec 2017</td>
  <td class="artist">kool as the gang</td>
  <td class="venue">100 club</td>
  <td class="link">
  <p class="availability out-of-stock">
    <span>Off Sale</span></p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is wrong, "artist" is the value of the "class" attribute try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<tr class="item">
<!-- <td class="image"><a href="https://www.stargreen.com/kool-as-the-gang-44415.html" title="KOOL AS THE GANG " class="product-image"><img src="https://www.stargreen.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/K/o/KoolAsTheGang.jpg" width="135" height="135" alt="KOOL AS THE GANG " /></a></td> -->
<td class="date">Sat, 30 Dec 2017</td>
<td class="artist">
                        kool as the gang                     </td>
<td class="venue">100 club</td>
<td class="link">
<p class="availability out-of-stock">
<span>Off Sale</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
td = soup.find('td',{'class': 'artist'})
print (td.text.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
kool as the gang
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

Look for the element within `container` whose `class` is 'artist' with the `select` method. Since there could be more than one, but you know there is only one, select the only element in the list, and request its `text` attribute.

```
>>> HTML = open('sven.htm').read()
>>> import bs4
>>> container = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> container.select('.artist')[0].text
'\n                        kool as the gang                     '
```